# Error in making a socket connection

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to run the program below, but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.createFrameHandler(ConnectionFactory.java:445)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:504)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
    at Recieve.main(Recieve.java:14)
```

The program I am trying to run is:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class Send {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello World!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I am not aware of making a socket connection, please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: What are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Looks like your trying to connect to your RabbitMQ instance running on localhost. Is the RabbitMQ instance up and running and ready to accept connections?

Comment: @Peter i dint got about running an RabbitMQ instance,con you please brief it out ?How to start its instance? i am following steps over here :http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Comment: You do know what your code will do? And I assume that you know what RabbitMQ is? Your code will try to connect to a RabbitMQ (message broker) instance running on localhost, then create a queue named "hello" and publish a message "Hello World!" to that queue. So in order for your code to work, a RabbitMQ serverinstance must be running on your localhost. Have you followed the instructions regarding installing a server perhaps (http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html)

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps you should follow for your code to work:

1. Download and install the latest Erlang.
2. Download the RabbitMQ server.
3. Install RabbitMQ Server
4. Compile and run your code and it should work by now.

Hope this helps.