# RabbitMQ "Hello World" example gives "Connection Refused"

Tags: java, exception, rabbitmq

II'm trying to make the "hello world" application from here: [RabbitMQ Hello World](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)

Here is the code of my producer class:

```
package com.mdnaRabbit.producer;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main( String[] argv) throws IOException{
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello World!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent" + "'");
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

And here what I get when implement this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.createFrameHandler(ConnectionFactory.java:445)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:504)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:533)
at com.mdnaRabbit.producer.App.main(App.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is causing this?

I found the solution to my problem here [Error in making a socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939074/error-in-making-a-socket-connection)

Comment: For reference, Google says В соединении отказано translates to Connection Refused.

Comment: Does this question help with your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939074/error-in-making-a-socket-connection

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't translate this. I didn't noticed it. well, thegrinner, that post descrybes the way of solving my problem, but I've solved it little earlier than see that post. thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To deal with it I installed RabbitMQ server.  If rabbitmq-server is not installed this error will be thrown.
Make sure you have installed RabbitMQ server and it's up and running by hitting http://localhost:15672/

Comment: More specifically, this error will be thrown if RabbitMQ is not running.

Answer (score 3):

**I got this "Connection Refused" error as well:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:588)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:612)
at ReceiveLogs.main(ReceiveLogs.java:14)
```

I had made a mistake by setting the IP address from inside `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` to the wrong ip address:

```
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=10.0.1.45
```

I removed this configuration parameter and the error goes away.

Comment: this. worked for me. We had set NODE_IP_ADDRESS to 127.0.0.1 so the listener were not able to connect to it, when I set the server IP address there, listeners started working.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem simply by executing:

```
 sudo rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the Rabbit MQ Server. The batch file to start this server is present under rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin>rabbitmq-server.bat start  then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it gave me the following error trying to start the server

`<Rabbit intall path>\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin>rabbitmq-server.bat start
ERROR: epmd error for host Protocol: inet_tcp: register/listen error: econnrefused: nxdomain (non-existing domain)`

What I did was add in my `host` file the following line:

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

And then the rabbitmq-server started. After this I didn't get the `connection refuse` error anymore. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Sometimes you just gotta reboot a mac.** Tried all the other solutions here and other things from different questions, and as dumb as it sounds, a reboot is what finally got it back to running and able to reach http://localhost:15672/

This was after I had done a `brew upgrade` (which is what probably put me in a bad state).

Answer (score 0):

You have to start Rabbit MQ Serever

In windows file name: RabbitMQ Service - start

You can use this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;

public class NewTaskController implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

     private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "test";

     private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "test";

     public NewTaskController(final String message) {
         this.message = message;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {

        //getting data from application.properties
         //for the rabbit_mq configuration

         ResourceBundle mRB = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");


         System.out.println("*****NewTaskController************"+mRB.getString("rabbitmq.port"));
        String rabbitmq_username = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.username");
        String rabbitmq_password = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.password");
                String rabbitmq_hostname = mRB.getString("rabbitmq.hostname");
                        int rabbitmq_port = Integer.parseInt(mRB.getString("rabbitmq.port"));
     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
     factory.setUsername(rabbitmq_username);
     factory.setPassword(rabbitmq_password);
     factory.setHost(rabbitmq_hostname);
     factory.setPort(rabbitmq_port);
     Connection conn;
     try {
     conn = factory.newConnection();
     Channel channel = conn.createChannel();

     channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", true);
     String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
     System.out.println(queueName);
     channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY);
     System.out.println("Producing message: " + message + " in thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
     channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, null, message.getBytes());

     try {
        channel.close();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     conn.close();
     } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
}
```

application.properties file:

```
rabbitmq.username=guest
rabbitmq.password=guest
rabbitmq.hostname=localhost
rabbitmq.port=5672
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple fix is indeed, `rabbitmq-server`, if you already have RabbitMQ installed locally.

I encountered this issue as a firewall issue after migrating from Mac OS X Sierra to High Sierra. I already had RabbitMQ installed. However, I kept getting this `Connection Refused` error. I had to do the following:

1. `brew uninstall rabbitmq`
2. `brew install rabbitmq`
3. `rabbitmq-server`
   (and allow firewall permissions)
4. Run app locally.